# Scan a directory to find files pointed by soft links

Tags: c, directory, operating-system, posix, symlink

I'm trying to do this exercise for my Operating Systems class: I'm supposed to pass a specific directory through command line to find any files in it pointed by soft links.

This is what I've done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

 DIR *dir_ptr;
 struct dirent *dir_str;
 struct stat buf;
 struct stat buf2;

 if(argc!=2)
 {
  printf("Error! I need a directory.\n");
  exit(-1);
 }


 if((dir_ptr=opendir(argv[1]))==NULL)       
 {
  printf("Opendir error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  exit(-1);
 }

 while((dir_str=readdir(dir_ptr))!=NULL)
 {
  lstat(dir_str->d_name, &buf);     
  if(S_ISLNK(buf.st_mode))
  {
   stat(dir_str->d_name, &buf2);
   printf("'%s' points to a file of %ld bytes.\n", dir_str->d_name, buf2.st_size);
  }

 }

 closedir(dir_ptr);
 exit(0);

}
```

Now here's my problem: this program just writes to standard output all soft links that point to a file of a certain size. Instead, I need it prints all the files pointed by a soft link. Secondly, strangely this program seems to work only if no directory is required, I mean, getting the current directory with `getcwd()`and passing the returned pathname to `opendir()`. This one infact doesn't even prints all the soft links in the passed directory.

Thanks in advance! Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Let us assume we have this directory named "my_directory" with these files:

```
justatext.txt
softlink1 (it points to justatext.txt)
justanothertext.txt
softlink2(it points to justanothertext)
```

When I pass "my_directory" through command line (./a.out my_directory), I want that the program writes to standard output "justatext.txt" and "justanothertext.txt" because these files in the directory are pointed by softlinks.
If I pass this directory to my program, no output is printed.

Comment: Please show us some example "input" (argument) and the expected and actual output. I also recommend that you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Use readlink() to obtain the path name stored in the symlink named as its argument (beware — it does not null terminate the string).

Comment: Do you want to display files that are target of a soft link? Even if the link is located in another directory?

Comment: @Gerhardh yes, I do. I want to display all files pointed by a soft link, preferably in the same directory, but it is not necessary.

Comment: I am not sure if you can detect whether a file is target of a link. You might have to scan all directories on all drives and search for links with a target within your directory.

Comment: What do you want `exit(-1)` to do? Exit codes can only be 0 to 127 in Linux. Common practice is to use `exit(1)`.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson you're completely right! I used `exit(-1)` to close the program returning an error, but it isn't possible with the exit function for the reason you gave. I'm using `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)' instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I've solved my problem. Summarizing all the advices in the comments, this is what I did and it seems to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>     
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

 DIR *dir_ptr;
 struct dirent *dir_str;
 struct stat buf;
 struct stat buf2;
 char *buf3;            
 ssize_t nbyte, bufsize;
 int flag=0;

 if(argc!=2)
 {
  printf("Error! I need a directory.\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 if((dir_ptr=opendir(argv[1]))==NULL)
 {
  printf("Opendir error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 chdir(argv[1]);    

 while((dir_str=readdir(dir_ptr))!=NULL)    
 {
  lstat(dir_str->d_name, &buf);     
  bufsize=buf.st_size+1;    
  if(buf.st_size==0)        
   bufsize=PATH_MAX;        

  buf3=malloc(bufsize); 
  if(buf3==NULL)
  {
   perror("malloc");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  nbyte=readlink(dir_str->d_name, buf3, bufsize);   

  if(S_ISLNK(buf.st_mode))  
  {
   stat(dir_str->d_name, &buf2);
   printf("%s is a file of %ld bytes pointed by a symbolic link (%s).\n", buf3, buf2.st_size, dir_str->d_name);
   flag+=1;
  }

 }

 if(flag==0)
  printf("No files pointed by a syslink found in this directory!\n");

 free(buf3);
 closedir(dir_ptr);
 exit(0);

}
```

First of all, I used `chdir()` in order to change the current directory with the one passed through command line; then I implemented `readlink()` to obtain the path name in the symbolic link named as its argument. Also I used `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` to close the program if an error occurs.

I don't know if this is fully correct. Please let me know if it's not so!